# Munkres, Chapter 2, question on locally finite family of sets

Tags: general-topology

I've been working through the Munkres Topology text on my own, and I am not sure if the following argument is correct.  Fishing around the internet a bit for some alternative answers and it looks like the approaches others have taken to this problem are not the same way that I approached it, so I'm concerned that I'm making some conceptual errors.  The problem:

Let {A$_{\alpha}$} be a collection of subsets of X.  Let X=$\cup_{\alpha}$A$_{\alpha}$.  Let f: X$\rightarrow$Y; suppose that f$\mid$A$_{\alpha}$ is continuous for each $\alpha$.  An indexed family of sets {A$_{\alpha}$} is said to be locally finite if each point of X has a neighborhood that intersects A$_{\alpha}$ for only finitely many values of $\alpha$.  Show that if the family {A$_{\alpha}$} is locally finite and each A$_{\alpha}$ is closed, then f is continuous.

Attempt at solution:

Let x $\in$ X.  Since there exists a neighborhood U$_{x}$ of x that intersects A$_{\alpha}$ for only finitely many $\alpha$, U$_{x}$ can be contained in a finite collection of A$_{\alpha}$'s.  So x $\in$ U$_{x}$ $\subset$ $\cup_{i=1}^{n}$A$_{i}$ $\subset$ X.  Then, since each A$_{i}$ is closed and f$\mid$A$_{i}$ continuous for each i, by repeated application of the Pasting Lemma, f$\mid$$\cup_{i=1}^{n}$A$_{i}$ is continuous.  Then, since U$_{x}$ $\subset$ $\cup_{i=1}^{n}$A$_{i}$, by restricting the domain (Theorem 18.2d), f$\mid$U$_{x}$ continuous.  Since it is given that such a neighborhood U$_{x}$ exists for each x $\in$ X, then X can be written as the union of open sets U$_{x}$, where f$\mid$U$_{x}$ is continuous for each x, and so by Theorem 18.2f (local formulation of continuity), f: X$\rightarrow$Y is continuous.

Feel like I'm missing something, or making some incorrect assumptions.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your argument is fine. An alternative that you may have encountered is first to prove the very useful fact that locally finite families are closure-preserving, meaning that if $\mathscr{C}$ is any locally finite family of sets, $\operatorname{cl}\bigcup\mathscr{C}=\bigcup_{C\in\mathscr{C}}\operatorname{cl}C$.

Then let $F$ be any closed subset of $Y$, and for each $\alpha\in A$ let $C_\alpha=(f\upharpoonright A_\alpha)^{-1}[F]\subseteq A_\alpha$. Then $C_\alpha$ is closed in $A_\alpha$ (since $f\upharpoonright A_\alpha$ is continuous) and hence in $X$. Moreover, $\mathscr{C}=\{C_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ is easily seen to be locally finite, so

$$f^{-1}[F]=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}C_\alpha=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}\operatorname{cl}C_\alpha=\operatorname{cl}\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}C_\alpha=\operatorname{cl}F\;,$$

and $F$ is closed.

Comment: This is good.  I just worked your proof out as well.  Thank you.

Comment: @mrmingus: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I hope you don't mind, but I have a question about the OP that I would like to direct towards you, since I am not sure mrmingus still visits us. It isn't clear to me why $U_x \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. What guarantees this? How does one go from having $U_x$ intersect finitely many $A_i$'s to being entirely covered by finitely many of them?

Comment: @user193319: It follows from the fact that $\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha=X$. Thus, $U_x\subseteq\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha$. Sets $A_\alpha$ that don’t intersect $U_x$ clearly don’t help to cover $U_x$, so $U_x\subseteq\bigcup\{A_\alpha:U_x\cap A_\alpha\ne\varnothing\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am still having trouble seeing why $\{A_\alpha ~|~ U_x \cap A_\alpha \neq \emptyset \}$ is finite. There is no disputing that $U_x$ is contained in $\bigcup \{A_\alpha ~|~ U_x \cap A_\alpha \neq \emptyset \}$, but I don't see what guarantees that this is a finite union, which is a crucial step in mrmingus' proof. I like mrmingus' proof. It is very nearly what I came up with, so it is very intuitive to me, but I am just having trouble with this one step.

Comment: @user193319: Let $\mathscr{A}=\{A_\alpha:U_x\cap A_\alpha\ne\varnothing\}$: by hypothesis $U_x$ intersects only finitely many of the sets $A_\alpha$, so $\mathscr{A}$ must be finite.